# How can I correctly install the DateTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I found the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/usage/) plugin on line and I have been trying to install it for the past 4 hours unfortunately I am unable to do so.

in the meta tags i added

```
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "css/dataTable/demo_page.css";
        @import "css/dataTable/demo_table_jui.css";
        @import "css/dataTable/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/cms_testing/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

yes the above 
Here is what I have done so far

```
    <script>
    $(function(){


    $('#internalActivities').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
```

file do exist I have done a double check.

Here is my html table

```
    <table id="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr><th colspan="3">Internal Activities</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><a href="display-call.php?account_id=9&amp;call_id=1128"><strong>Initial Development</strong></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">05/23/2013 06:19 AM</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><em>Call Result: Message Delivered - Follow up in 21 days</em>
                <br /><p class="sub_note">Moving to bottom of list</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;"><a href="display-call.php?account_id=9&amp;call_id=1052"><strong>Stage 2 Development</strong></a></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">04/19/2013 11:05 AM</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><em>Call Result: Partial Discussion</em>
                <br /><p class="sub_note">awef</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I don't get any error but it is not display the tables as it should.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I have. in fact I am using more jQuery and they are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of using collspan in some `td`. U should not merge two columns. See my HTML coding. Its working if u do like this.

```
<div>
        <table id="internalActivities" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Internal Activities
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                        <a href="display-call.php?account_id=9&amp;call_id=1128"><strong>Initial Development </strong></a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        05/23/2013 06:19 AM
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        name
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <em>Call Result: Message Delivered - Follow up in 21 days </em>
                        <br />
                        <p class="sub_note">
                            Moving to bottom of list
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                        <a href="display-call.php?account_id=9&amp;call_id=1052"><strong>Stage 2 Development </strong></a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        04/19/2013 11:05 AM
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        name
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <em>Call Result: Partial Discussion </em>
                        <br />
                        <p class="sub_note">
                            awef
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes that is correct as I just ready on DataTables website that DataTables does not support colspan at all.

Comment: K after u called datatable(), u can merge the td. But u cant do it before datatable() called.